# Variable comparison problems

Tags: c#, .net, comparison-operators

I'm still relatively new to C# and the answer to this is probably pretty obvious, but I'm struggling to solve it

I have an enum defined as follows:

```
enum Request {
    None = 0,
    GetData,
    SendData,
    some other values...
};
```

I then have two variables both defined as type Request as follows

```
Request currentRequest; // This is a class member variable
Request request; // This is a local variable within a method.
```

The first variable is assigned using currentRequest = Request.GetData;
The second local variable request is assigned using request = (Request)data, where data is byte of value 1  (as the value is being decoded from a buffer of USB data being received).  I don't know if this is relevant but mention it just in case.

I want to compare them within the method in which the second variable is declared, I originally did it like this:

```
if(request != currentRequest)
{
    // Throw an exception
}
```

This works most of the time, but occaisionally the exception is thrown because the two values don't equate, however when I check them in the debugger they are both equal to Request.GetData.  This got me thinking that the variables may be pointers to objects rather than values so I tried also using...

```
!request.Equals(currentRequest)
```

and

```
request.CompareTo(currentRequest)!=0
```

and similarly both of these work most of the time but occaisionally fail even though when the values are checked in the debugger they are both Request.GetData.

What's really confused me is that it works most of the time, just fails occaisionally - I'd expect it to either work or not work consistently.

Any ideas?

Comment: enums are integers and the comparison is definitely not bugged - how are you getting the values of request and currentRequest?

Comment: The only way they cannot be `==` is when 'comparing' boxed instances, which is NOT the case here.

Comment: Are you sure that in your code there are not boxing/unboxing operations with request and currentRequest?

Comment: @Praetor12: If they were unboxed, there would be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the variables are genuinely of type `Request` then that's a *value* type, and using `==` should be absolutely fine.

I suspect that the debugger is showing you something slightly odd. I suggest you make the exception include both `request` and `currentRequest` to show you what's going on.

Comment: I spoke to an old colleague who is experienced in writing USB code, he gave me some direction.  The code I mention above occurs in callback from the USB device whenever new data is received, what appears to be happening is that the comparison is genuinely failing, but by the time the breakpoint has been hit and the values displayed in the debugger a second callback has fired which is modifying the currentRequest variable so the debugger displays the changed value, not the comparison value.  This was proven by writing the values of the two variables to the console. Thanks everyone who replied!

Comment: @RichardBaxter: It would be worth encapsulating the values of the callback into an immutable object to avoid them changing in this sort of situation - so you can process one "message" at a time.